# Instagram linear gradient with Expo

Tags: css, react-native, linear-gradients

I'm working on a react-native app using [Expo](https://docs.expo.io).

```
<Button
  icon={
     <FontAwesome
       name="send"
       size={24}
       color={'white'}
     />
    }
    text={'Send Content'}
    activeOpacity={0.8}
    textStyle={{ fontWeight: '700' }}
    buttonStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 20, height: 55 }}
    onPress={() => console.log('send')}
    ViewComponent={require('expo').LinearGradient}
    linearGradientProps={{
      colors: ['#f68ba0', '#ec407a'],
      start: [1, 0],
      end: [0.2, 0],
     }}
  />
```

With [Native Elements](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements), you can implement Buttons with Linear Gradient such as above.

I'd like to have the same Linear Gradient as the 'Instagram' logo.

[image: Example]

Could you help me to implement that ?
Thanks for your time

Comment: it's not a linear gradient, it's seems a conic gradient

Comment: Oh okay. Well i don't mind if it is approximative. I'd like the reproduce the same 'feels' out of it

Comment: check radial-gradient and multiple background ;) You can combien many radial/linear-gradient then adjust colors to approximate this

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was using nativebase

```
import { IconButton, Icon, Box } from 'native-base'
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons"

const Instagram = () => {

    const gradient_codes = [
        '#fccc63',
        '#fbad50',
        '#cd486b',
        '#8a3ab9',
    ]

    return (
        <Box
            bg={{
                linearGradient: {
                    colors: gradient_codes,
                    start: [0, 0.9],
                    end: [0.5, 0],
                }
            }}
            borderRadius={24}>
            <IconButton
                icon={<Icon as={AntDesign} name='instagram' />}
                _icon={{
                    color: 'white'
                }}
            />
        </Box>
    )
}
```

It should look like this
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7x1O.jpg)

Answer (score -2):

It's quite simple using CSS3 radial-gradient!

```
<span class="instagram">
  <span class="fa fa-instagram"></span>
</span>

.instagram {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 220px;
  line-height: 250px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #d6249f;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%,#d6249f 60%,#285AEB 90%);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
```

Look over here: https://codepen.io/jonasloerken/pen/rJzBjj

Comment: Thanks for the example Jonas !
But the implement here is a bit different, such as :
linearGradientProps={{
      colors: ['#f68ba0', '#ec407a'],
      start: [1, 0],
      end: [0.2, 0],
     }}

It is the color and their range.
I'd like to have an implementation that has the same 'feels' and theme as instagram. Closest as possible

Comment: This answer is about HTML/CSS, while the question is about React Native, so it does not really fit.